# AngularJS Factory: undefined is not a function

Tags: angularjs, function, resources, undefined, promise

I wrote the following factory service in AngularJS, but when I try to call the factory service in my RootController, I got the "undefined is not a function" error in my console.

**MyService.js:**

```
(function() {
  angular.module('serviceTestApp')
    .factory('MyService', ['$resource', '$log', '$q', '$http', MyService]);

  function MyService($log, $resource, $http, $q) {
    var name = "Tom";

    var getName = function() {
      return name;
    }; //getName

    var changeName = function(newName) {
      name = newName;
    }; //changeName

    var getIP = function() {
      var deferredObj = $q.defer();
      $resource('http://jsonip.com').query().$promise.then(function(result) {
        deferredObj.resolve(result);
      }, function(errorMsg) {
        deferredObj.reject(errorMsg);
      });

      return deferredObj.promise;
    }; //getIP

    return {
      getName: getName,
      changeName: changeName,
      getIP: getIP
    };

  }

}());
```

in my RootController, I try to call the services, and everything worked until I call the getIP() service - return a promise object. Does anyone see anything wrong?

**RootController.js:**

```
(function() {
  angular.module('serviceTestApp')
    .controller('RootCtrl', ['$http', '$log', '$scope', 'MyService', RootCtrl]);

  function RootCtrl($log, $scope, $http, MyService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.message = "hello world from RootController";

    MyService.changeName("Henry Tudor");
    vm.message = "my name is: " + MyService.getName();

    MyService.getIP().query().then(function(data) {
      $log.info('in the promise, ip is: ' + data.ip);
      vm.message = vm.message + ', your IP is ' + data.ip;

    }, function(error) {
      vm.message = vm.message + ', error: ' + error;
    });

  }

}());
```

Comment: Did stack trace indicate a line error? -  `MyService.getIP()` is returning a promise. Promise API does not have a `query()` function call - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: yes, the console complains about this line: $resource('http://jsonip.com').query().$promise.then(function(result)

Comment: Did you add your factory to your index.html file correctly, so it gets loaded ?

Answer (score 1):

It may sound stupid, but I've located the cause for the error:

The API used in the $resource() returns a single JSON object:

```
{"ip":"2601:0:b840:8077:a97f:ee9c:f5b8:1643","about":"/about","Pro!":"http://getjsonip.com"}
```

however, the query() expects an array, not a JSON object. 
After changing to another API that returns an array in JSON format, it works. Sigh, wasted my 2 hours.

thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

in order to use your service like that

```
MyService.getName()
```

that mean you have a service called `MyService` and returns a function called `getName`

but in your case it dosen't you have to change
your return to something like that

```
 return {
      getName: function() {return getName();},
      changeName: function() {return changeName();},
      getIP: function() {return getIP();}
    };
```

Comment: check that question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214639/i-get-custom-method-indefined-error-when-i-encapsulate-http-service-in-custom-s/28216433#28216433